# Angular: Cannot use module imported in app module in a component from a different module

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I have installed flex-layout https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/ version `^2.0.0-beta.9`.

In my application, I imported and added `FlexLayoutModule` to the `imports` array in `app.module.ts`

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    LayoutModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

When I try to use the `fxLayout` directive in a component's template in another module, it doesn't have any effect.

However, when I add the `FlexLayoutModule` to this "other" module where the component is defined, it works fine.

Did I miss something?

Comment: you need to add `FlexLayoutModule` to shared module

Comment: You should probably export `FlexLayoutModule ` in app.module in order to use it in other modules

Comment: Yes that worked thanks. But why doesnt the documentation state that?  Does it mean that those modules imported by app module are not passed to the other modules automatically?

Comment: hi, i have the same problem but i can't understand how you exactly solved it? can you show the code? how did you export the modules?

Answer (score 0):

add your new module to the ngModule declarations:
This is an easy one to overlook and can be frustrating.